# Django: QuerySet object has no attribute

Tags: django, view, attributeerror

I get an `AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'ratings'` when trying to do something like this in my view:

```
def index(request):
    thing_list = Thing.ratings.cumulative_score()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'thing_list':thing_list})
```

My model:

```
from ratings.models import Ratings

class Thing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
    rating = Ratings()
```

While using [django-simple-ratings](https://github.com/coleifer/django-simple-ratings) app. This [link](https://github.com/coleifer/django-simple-ratings/blob/master/ratings/models.py#L206) references where `cumulative_score` is defined in that module. How do I use cumulative score?  Thank you for your ideas!

Comment: Post the full traceback somewhere (pastebin, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've referenced `ratings` in your view, but defined the manager attribute as `rating` (no 's').

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, solving this error has resulted in another, which I referenced [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227478/django-attributeerror-using-ratings-app) if you have any further ideas. Thanks for your input.