# Django: AttributeError using ratings app

Tags: django, view, attributeerror

This is somewhat an extension of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211551/django-queryset-object-has-no-attribute), but after solving that problem I am getting a different `AttributeError`. This one reads  `'_RatingsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'cumulative_score'` when trying to do something like this in my view:

```
def index(request):
    thing_list = Thing.ratings.cumulative_score()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'thing_list':thing_list})
```

My model:

```
from ratings.models import Ratings

class Thing(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
    ratings = Ratings()
```

While using [django-simple-ratings](https://github.com/coleifer/django-simple-ratings) app. This [link](https://github.com/coleifer/django-simple-ratings/blob/master/ratings/models.py#206) references where `cumulative_score` is defined in that module. How do I use cumulative score for multiple objects?  Thank you for your ideas!

---

EDIT: views.py:

```
def index(request):
    thing_list = Thing.objects.all()
    thing_list.ratings.cumulative_score()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'thing_list':thing_list})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its an instance method, so you must first retrive Thing from the db.

```
t = Thing.objects.get(xxxx)
t.ratings.cumulative_score()
```

---

Comment: What if I need to get the score for multiple objects?

Comment: I am saying you need to first get your thing, and then call ratings.cumulative_score()

Comment: I want to do something like my edit above so that can get the `cumulative_score` of multiple objects, but it does not work. Do you have any ideas? Thank you for your thoughts

Comment: If you want to get the aggregate cumulative score for multiple objects, you should write some additional code to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up comment to your post. If it performs aggregation, is there a way to get the cumulative score for multiple objects? How can I do that? Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Are you trying to sum all, or are you using a query?

Comment: I just want a for loop through a list of scores in my template, so I guess I am using a query. Trying to do something like in my edit above..